# The line is tangent to a parabola

Tags: conic-sections

The line $y = 4x-7$ is tangent to a parabola that has a $y$-intercept of $-3$ and the line $x=\frac{1}{2}$ as its axis of symmetry. Find the equation of the parabola. I really need help solving this question. THx

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: y=4x-7 is a line tangent to the parabola.

Comment: The conditions that the $y$-intercept is $-3$ and the vertex is at $x = \frac 12$ tell you these two points on the parabola: $(0,-3)$ and $(1,-3).$ One of those points happens to be on the line $y = 4x - 7.$ This gives a quick solution for this particular problem, but it seems not a good solution method in general for problems of this kind.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: remember that the equation of a parabola is $y = ax^2 + bx +c$ and $c$ is the intersection with the axis y (that you know in your exercise). In addition, you have to solve a system between your generic parabola and the tangent line and impose that they are only one point of intersection (putting $\Delta = 0$). The last condition is $- \frac{b}{2a} =\frac{1}{2}$. In this way, you'll find $a$, $b$ and $c$.

It's simpler if you use before the condition $c = -3$ and $- \frac{b}{2a} =\frac{1}{2}$ and then solve the system.

Comment: I think the vertex of a parabola has the $x$-coordinate $-\frac{b}{\color{red}{2}a}$. So, we have the following: $-\frac{b}{2a}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: yes, of course. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Let the formula for the parabola be $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

**1. *y*-intercept**: $y$-intercept is @ $(0,-3)$ so we have: $f(0)=-3 \Rightarrow c=-3$.

**2. Vertex**: The vertex is @ $(x,\frac{1}{2})$ and we now that at the vertex, the derivative is equal to zero, so we have:
$f'(\frac{1}{2})=0 \Leftrightarrow 2a\cdot(\frac{1}{2})+b=0 \Rightarrow a+b=0$.

**3. Line tangent to parabola**: Furthermore, the line $y=4x-7$ is tangent to the parabola (and therefore $4x-7=ax^2+bx+c$ has only one solution).

Intersection point: $ax^2+bx+c=4x-7 \Rightarrow ax^2+x(b-4)+(c+7)$. Discriminant must be zero in order to have only one intersection point, so we have $D=b^2-4ac=(b-4)^2-4a(c+7)=0$.

Now, we substitute $c=-3$ and $a=-b$ and solve for $a$:

$(b-4)^2+4b(-3+7)=0 \Rightarrow (b-4)^2+16b=0 \Rightarrow b=-4$. $a=-b$ so $a=4$.

The formula is $\boxed{y=4x^2-4x-3}$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let the parabola be defined by the function $y = f(x)$ and let $g(x) = f(x) - 4x + 7.$
Then $y = g(x)$ is a parabola passing through $(0,4)$
and it has slope $-4$ at $x = \frac 12.$
In addition, the parabola described by $y = g(x)$ is tangent to the $x$-axis
so $g(x)$ can be written $g(x) = a(x - p)^2.$
We can also write the derivative of $g$ with respect to $x$ as
$g^\prime(x) = 2a(x - p).$

This gives us $g(0) = ap^2 = 4$ and $g^\prime\left(\frac 12\right) = a(1 - 2p) = -4.$
Then
$$ \frac{ap^2}{a(1 - 2p)} = \frac{4}{-4}, $$
and we can simplify both sides of this to conclude that
$$ \frac{p^2}{1 - 2p} = -1. $$
Rearranging terms,
$$ p^2 = -1(1 - 2p), $$
$$ p^2 - 2p + 1 = 0 $$
Solve for $p;$ that is the $x$-coordinate of the (unique) point where $g(x) = 0.$
It's also the $x$-coordinate of the unique point where $f(x) = 4x - 7.$
Given $p,$ use one of the previous equations (such as $ap^2 = 4$) to solve for $a.$
You can then expand $g(x)$ as a simple polynomial.
Use the fact that $f(x) = g(x) + 4x - 7$ to write $f(x).$

You can solve the problem without introducing the additional parabola $y = g(x),$
but I like the geometric intuition of this method. The key idea is that by a
change of coordinates ($y \rightarrow y - 4x + 7$), we transform the parabola
$y = f(x)$ into one with a (somewhat) easier geometry (or at least so I think).

It seems a mere coincidence that the point of tangency of $y = f(x)$ and $y = 4x - 7$
just happens to be a point that we could already know is on $y = f(x)$ by virtue of
the axis of symmetry and the one given point of that parabola.
That's not a necessary condition for this problem to be solvable.
It does suggest a clever insight that for this particular problem that
leads to a solution more quickly than the steps above, because you can find
the point of tangency almost right away.